# setNeedsDisplayInRect: causes the whole view to be updated

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm working on a painting app that uses CoreGraphics for rendering. My problem is, for performance, I am trying to limit the updates to only certain portions of the view that have changed. For that, I use setNeedsDisplayInRect:, but sometimes the view updates its entire content, causing stuttering. This is particularly evident on the 3rd generation iPads, but it also happens in the simulator and the iPad2 to a lesser degree. I am trying to remove this behavior.

To showcase the problem, I created a simple "single view" project using the template in Xcode. Created a custom UIView subclass which I set as the view controller's view in the xib file.

Added this to the UIViewController:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Asks that the view refreshes a smal rectangle
    [self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
}
```

Added this to the MyView (my custom view):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Just log what is being updated
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
}
```

And that's it. If I run the app on the 3rd ten iPad (the actual device), the logs show the view repainting itself in its entierty from time to time (like very frequently). This is so frustrating and I am out of ideas

UPDATE: Here are some logs. It definitely shows the full view being updated sometimes. I am trying to make it stop completely but can't figure how to...

```
2012-05-04 08:34:01.851 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.184 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.197 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.215 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.226 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.242 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.258 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.274 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.290 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.306 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.322 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.338 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.354 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.371 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.387 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.403 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.419 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.439 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:34:30.457 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
```

Also if I stop moving for over 10s or so and resume, it definitely does it very consistently:

```
2012-05-04 08:34:33.305 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:34:33.321 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
2012-05-04 08:35:00.202 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:35:00.221 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:35:00.234 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2012-05-04 08:35:00.251 TestUpdateArea[45745:707] {{10, 10}, {20, 20}}
```

Comment: In my case, when drawRect called after setNeedsDisplayInRect the **first time**, the rect is full bounds (don't ask my why), any next call it's exactly the rect I specified as parameter in setNeedsDisplayInRect. Did you test the touch move more than one time?

Comment: It happens mostly on the device directly. But you can make it happen on the simulator if you move your finger around and then wait for about 10 or 15 seconds, then touch and move again. On the iPad3 device, it happens even while the finger is moving. Sooo annoying :)

Comment: I posted @ this a while back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299018/setneedsdisplayinrect-bug-in-ios5). It seemed to be only on the first call. I never found a cause/fix and just moved on since I didn't need that level of performance optimization. Can you test for rect == view size and not draw? Maybe not an option.

Comment: I tried testing for the rect, but unfortunately, if I exit the drawRect method without drawing what the rect covers, the view winds up empty because the view is cleared automatically because calling drawRect. This is ridiculously frustrating, it sounds so simple.

Comment: Weird problem.  Have you considered working around it by making each drawing action into it's own view or layer, and then just stacking them one on top of the other?  That way, you would only be "dirtying" and having to redraw a fresh layer each time, and you would be leveraging the compositing engine to deal with which other layers need to be updated.  If you try that, let us know if it gives better performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html)

they said :

> because of the way that iPhone/iPod touch/iPad updates its screen, the
>   entire view will be redrawn if you call `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` or
>   `-setNeedsDisplay:`.

Also

> Each UIView is treated as a single element. When you request a redraw, in part or whole, by calling `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` or `-setNeedsDisplay:`, the entire view will be marked for updates.

so I think you need to use subviews to update independent rect of the whole View.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What would be the point in having the two methods then. And why would it only work sometimes?

Comment: I read some where thats a bug in iOS 5 .. did you try that on iOS 4 ?

Comment: It does it in iOS4 to a much lesser extent.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The answer from @Nick Lockwood below is more accurate.

Answer (score 14):

**The accepted answer is wrong** (or at least misleading).

Here's a simple code example of setNeedsDisplayInRect: working as advertised:

http://charcoaldesign.co.uk/resources/chalkboard.zip

I suspect that the Apple documentation is trying to explain the fact that on iOS every view backing image is converted to an OpenGL texture and the entire screen is re-composited every frame. That distinct from the question of whether your code has to clear and redraw the entire contents of the view's backing texture or not.

By using setNeedsDisplayInRect: you can avoid expensive redrawing of content that doesn't change between frames (which uses core graphics and is not hardware accelerated). The whole screen will still be redrawn regardless, but that doesn't matter because it's hardware accelerated by the GPU, unlike the code in drawRect:

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue: namely wanting to update only a portion of a UIView with a call to setNeedsDisplayInRect: which I pass a valid CGRect of the correct size (proved with Break Points, and Logs).  Under iOS 4.2.1 (on my iPhone 3G) the UIView keeps its original image and only updates the portion specified by the CGRect, but under iOS 5.1 (on my iPhone 4S) the entire UIView is redrawn in transparent black (how black can be transparent is beyond me), with the area specified by the CGRect being drawn in correctly after.  It seems to be either: an error on Apple's part that they are not implementing setNeedsDisplayInRect: correctly and just passing it to setNeedsDisplay:; or it was a wilful decision based on how the new iOS handles interaction with the actual screen architecture.  Either way, it would seem that for the time being developers will either have to wear the cost of updating the entire UIView every time a graphical change occurs, or use some iOS detection and implement different screen drawing code depending on the iOS being dealt with.

I have done some testing with the UIView property clearsContextBeforeDrawing (which according to the documentation should allow targeted drawing operations), but the results are identical for both YES and NO, so it would appear to be the implementation of the drawing code.

As for the CGRect being of the incorrect size during updates: is it being set somewhere else prior to, or after, the drawing call.  I set my CGRect just before the call to setNeedsDisplayInRect:, and then set it to CGRectNull on the last few lines of the drawRect method (this is so if the drawRect method is called by the system my code will not fire).  After going back to your code snippet I can see it gets set in-line, which means it's a System Call that's redrawing the entire UIView, and hence why the CGRect is the entire view.

I'll keep digging into this, but I fear that until Apple either disclose their reasoning for the change to setNeedsDisplayInRect:, or fix the apparent bug, we may be looking at updating the entire contents of a UIView for every graphical update (which could be potentially very 'expensive').

Comment: It's what I feared. I opened a tech support ticket with Apple and they silently closed it and credited the ticket cost back to my account without saying a word...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of devices available to me, but I have great news anyway! As someone who has been wishing for this functionality on iOS for years, I can assert that iOS8.0+ brings this functionality. I've tried on both simulator and device for 8.0, 8.1, 8.2

I haven't tried this since iOS6. So I'm not sure if its available in iOS7 or not. Perhaps someone else can confirm.

Please join with me in cheering endlessly for `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` functioning as documented!